# In the django background, the text is too long to look good, how to shrink the text

Tags: python, django

In the django background, the text is too long to look good, how to shrink the text: [image]

Comment: What do you mean by shrink? Do you want to, say, replace some text with an ellipsis?

Comment: yes, I want a long text to display fixed-length characters in the xadmin backend, and the remaining characters are replaced with ellipsis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can truncate long text by one of the followings

[**truncatechars**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

```
{{ value|truncatechars:7 }}
```

If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel i…".

[**truncatewords**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords)

```
{{ value|truncatewords:2 }}
```

If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel is …".

**Update:**

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    @property
    def short_name(self):
        return truncatechars(self.name, 50)
```

In `admin.py`

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['short_name']
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I meant， I want a long text to display fixed-length characters in the xadmin backend, and the remaining characters are replaced with ellipsis

Comment: That means you need this in django admin?

Comment: almostly, I need this in django xadmin

Comment: Thank you for your answer which helps me solve the problem, a great  guy !

Comment: But if so, the original verbose_name will be Invalid，how can I do with it？

Comment: I am not clear about your query. Can you explain more?